# gem -v, rvm Errors

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, rvm, bash

Level: **Beginner**.

I begin installing brew, rvm and ruby *2.1.0* today, and I encountered many errors. I think I may have screw up my entire terminal because I copy pasted some solutions from stackoverflow.

When I type: `gem -v`:

**Error:**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/cusxio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/security.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/cusxio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/cusxio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/cusxio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/executable-hooks-1.3.1/gem_make.out
 (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/cusxio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.4/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

When I typed: `rvm doctor`:

**Error**

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/cusxio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.0'.
```

Question:

How Can I actually make sure that I have everything installed perfectly on MacOSX ? (brew, rvm, ruby, gems,  ? )

Answer (score 0):

The error text: `PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/cusxio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin` says cleanly. So verify your **[.bash-profile](/questions/tagged/.bash-profile)**, and **[.bashrc](/questions/tagged/.bashrc)**, and make sure that `source` call to [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) is placed in the **[.bash-profile](/questions/tagged/.bash-profile)**, and it is the last thing that modifies the *[path](/questions/tagged/path)* variable. Then reload the shell or [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) with `rvm reload`.